# For a given range of (x,y) how do I return the list of files with numbers within x, y in their name

Tags: python, regex, glob

I have got a list of files named posture0 posture 1 posture 2 etc up to 4000. I want to use a function that takes this range and gives me the file pattern around it. The reason why I tried this I might want to get certain ranges of files (1-300),(2-219) In order to achieve this I have tried these so far:

**Automate a regex search pattern.**

I have found the module rgxg which does automate the pattern searching. For 0-180 it generated this result.

```
(180|1[0-7][0-9]|0?[0-9]{1,2})
```

So this was my regex.

```
posture+(180|1[0-7][0-9]|0[0-9]{1,2})+.jpg
```

This didn't work because it should have gotten files like posture0 and to posture180.jpg. It got them although 0-100 was missing and also patterns like 1000 were also found with this regex.

And later on I ran this pattern on a python code.

```
import re

rootdir = "postures"

regex = re.compile('posture+(180|1[0-7][0-9]|0[0-9]{1,2})+.jpg')

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
  for file in files:
    if regex.match(file):
       print(file)
```

It returns files but it also returns file 0-1500 and it doesn't return numbers between 0-99.

I have also searched glob but it seems I can't find such functionality on it.

Edit:Since I have had the feedback of my question being not clear.I will try to clarify it.

**The Question:**
Is there a way to automate the search strings in regex? The one I have tried didn't work well for me since the cases I mentioned weren't captured.
Thanks :)

Comment: You should not add `+` anywhere you like. Escape literal dot. Use `re.compile(r'posture(180|1[0-7][0-9]|[0-9]{1,2})\.jpg')`. And probably use `re.fullmatch` if you need a whole string match.

Comment: Do you need a literal `+` sign? If so then you want to use `\+` in addition to `\.`.

Comment: What exactly is your question? Currently this is more a description of what you've done, rather than a question. If you separate out the actual bit you're asking a bit more clearly it might be easier to answer.

Comment: Is the question 'For a given range of (x,y) how do I return the list of files with numbers within x, y in their name?'

Comment: @theo-brown yes exactly that was the best way to describe it. Changed the title thanks to your comment :)

Comment: I cannot find any *module rgrx* - where can I find it?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew The module name was wrong. It was rgxg you can check installation over here.  https://rgxg.github.io/#:~:text=What%20does%20it%20do%3F,db8%3Aaaaa%3A%3A%2F64).

Comment: Just came across https://pypi.org/project/rgxg/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution to what I think is your question. It implements a function that takes a path to a directory, a lower value and an upper value, then returns all filenames that contain the number within range defined by the lower and upper values.

```py
import os
import re

def get_filenames_in_range(path_to_directory, lower_bound, upper_bound):
    files = []
    # Iterate through files in current directory
    for f in os.listdir(path_to_directory):
        # os.listdir captures directories as well as files
        # so filter just for files
        if os.path.isfile(f):
            # Perform a regex match for numbers
            match = re.findall(r'\d+', f)
            # If numbers are found, check whether they are within range
            if match:
                number = int(match[0])
                if number >= lower_bound and number <= upper_bound:
                    files.append(f)
    return files
```

Comment: Why did you += on files? Files is a list. Can you add to it? Also the function doesn't seem to work on the file list I have

Comment: @Batselot in general you can use `+=` to append a non-iterable item to a list. However in this case it's actually better to use `files.append`, thanks!

Comment: wow didn't know that.  Btw I call the function like this but am I calling it wrong? print(get_filenames_in_range("posture02",0,100)) I get an empty list after this.

Comment: You need to specify the path to the directory that you're searching, `path_to_directory`. This either has to be relative to where you are running the function from, or absolute. If your data is stored in `/home/user/experiment/data` and you're running the script from `/home/user`, you could specify the relative path `experiment/data` or the absolute path `/home/user/experiments/data`

Comment: Okay I went through debugging a bit. It seems it returned false when it ran if os.path.isfile. Removing that line made the code work perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: Are `posture0`, `posture1` etc files or directories?

Comment: They were .jpg files. But for some reason they returned false that's why the list was empty.